# Как распарсить html страницу на объекты в qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Нужно получить информацию, которая находится между html тегов (Например, `div id="content"`).

Исходный код страницы я получил, но какими инструментами QT, C++ или либами можно построить дерево из html, чтобы легко выдергивать содержимое тегов?

Comment: А вы каким классом получили страницу?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете пойти другим путем – все действия, которые необходимо произвести со страницей выполняйте с помощью JavaScript, а в C++ обрабатывайте лишь результат. Поясню.

Представим, что у вас есть `QWebEngineView`

```
QWebEngineView *view;
```

Вы можете назначить функцию обратного вызова для события загрузки страницы

```
connect(view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), SLOT(finishLoading(bool)));
```

Вызвать загрузку целевой страницы

```
view->load(QUrl(requestUrl));
```

Когда загрузка будет выполнена, для упрощения работы с JavaScript, добавим JQuery. JQuery – строка полученная из ресурсного файла. После добавления JQuery, добавьте ваш JavaScript код и обработчик результата. Функция `finishLoading` может выглядеть следующим образом

```
void MyClass::finishLoading(bool) {
    view->page()->runJavaScript(JQuery::Instance()->Code());
    view->page()->runJavaScript(YOUR_JS_CODE, invoke(this, &MyClass::onResultCallback));
}
```

Где, `YOUR_JS_CODE` – QString с кодом обработки страницы. Например

```
const QString YOUR_JS_CODE = " \
    function doSomething(){ \
        var results = $('.content'); \
        if (results != 'undefined')  \
            return results.html(); \
        return ''; \
    }; doSomething();";
```

Обратите внимание, что необходимо вызвать добавленный код (последняя строка).

В завершении, вам необходимо обработать результат

```
void MyClass::onResultCallback(const QVariant& returnValue) {
    QString result = "";
    bool isOk = false;

    result = returnValue.toString(&isOk);

    if (!isOk) {
        // Обработка ошибки
        return;
    }

    // Логика работы с результатом.
}
```

Для справки рекомендую посмотреть [fancybrowser](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qtwebenginewidgets-fancybrowser-example.html) или основанный на нем [querychecker](https://github.com/chabanovsky/querychecker).

Answer (score 3):

Если парсить через `QWebKit`, тогда используйте методы [findAllElements](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#findAllElements) и [findFirstElement](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#findFirstElement).

Нужно добавить в `pro`-файл в `QT += webkit`. Для `Qt5` нужно также добавить `QT += webkitwidgets`

И принклудить:

```
#include <QWebPage>
#include <QWebFrame>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QWebElementCollection>
#include <QDebug>
```

В `Qt5` инклуды будут такими:

```
#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebPage>
#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebFrame>
```

Код:

```
QWebPage page;
page.mainFrame()->setHtml("<a><b/><div id=\"content\">!!!</div><div id=\"content\">@@@</div></a>");
qDebug() << page.mainFrame()->toHtml();
foreach (QWebElement el, page.mainFrame()->findAllElements("#content").toList()) {
    qDebug() << el.toInnerXml();
}
```

Консоль:

```
"<html><head></head><body><a><b><div id="content">!!!</div><div id="content">@@@</div></b></a></body></html>" 
"!!!" 
"@@@"
```

В `QWebKit` для поиска используются css-селекторы -- аналог xpath-запросов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но беда в том что в последних версиях Qt нет возможности использовать Qwebkit. Вместо него как я понимаю QtWebengine. Вот как добиться этого с помощью него.

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать за что мне минус поставили, за работающий пример? :) @Duracell, минус вам [не я](http://savepic.ru/9928635.png), если что, поставил :)

Comment: @ЮрийВатаман, обновил ответ. Компилировал и запускал на Qt 5.4.2

Comment: @gil9red - извиняюсь, исправил, думал нахожусь в другой теме, этот минус был другому человеку, за другой ответ.

Comment: @gil9red , автор, вероятно, имеет в виду версию Qt 5.6, где действительно QtWebKit не подключить.

Comment: @alexis031182, возможно, тогда нужно дополнительно проверять для 5.6 или искать другой путь :)

Comment: @gil9red , да, Вы правы, но больше нет смысла использовать QtWebKit в новых проектах, тем более что 5.6 отмечена как "с длительной поддержкой". Поэтому остаётся только использовать сторонние парсеры, либо как-то работать с QtWebEngine. Кстати, у нас здесь на сайте ещё никто не касался темы использования `QWebChannel`, плюс парсинг через javascript. Это мне видится хорошим вариантом, но я пока ещё даже не пробовал копать в эту сторону. Если делали что-то подобное, поделитесь, по возможности.

Comment: Упс, пока писал комментарий, уже опубликовали ответ в обозначенном ключе :))

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить парсинг через `Qt XML`, я не знаю будет ли он работать в HTML, по идее должен, далее выдержка из `Qt Assistant`, из описания класса `QDomDocument`. Если нужны какие-то конкретные вопросы, то пишите в комментарии. Если хотите парсить html любой вложенности, то нужно использовать рекурсивные вызовы.
И не забудьте в `*.pro` добавить `QT += xml`.

```
QDomDocument doc("mydocument");
  QFile file("mydocument.xml");
  if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
      return;
  if (!doc.setContent(&file)) {
      file.close();
      return;
  }
  file.close();

  // print out the element names of all elements that are direct children
  // of the outermost element.
  QDomElement docElem = doc.documentElement();

  QDomNode n = docElem.firstChild();
  while(!n.isNull()) {
      QDomElement e = n.toElement(); // try to convert the node to an element.
      if(!e.isNull()) {
          cout << qPrintable(e.tagName()) << endl; // the node really is an element.
      }
      n = n.nextSibling();
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Я бы лично парсил с помощью обычной std::string, делал бы так:

1) Считал бы все содержимое запроса в переменную std::string.

2) Далее методом find - находил бы нужные теги и клал бы их в контейнер строк, чтобы потом воспроизвести иерархическое древо тегов

3) Далее методом erase - выдергивал бы внутренности нужного тега, по необходимости

4) Ну и создал бы простенькие алгоритм для определения вложенности тегов

Comment: а также можно было парсить регулярками, но лучше так не делать. Парсинг html/xml нужно делать соответствующим парсером плюс есть xpath-запросы и css-селекторы.

Comment: @gil9red - был вопрос:  "какими инструментами QT, C++ или либами можно построить дерево из html" - я привел средствами с++