# Запуск готового файла .bat в Qt Quick?

Tags: c++, qt, bat

Как запустить готовый файл .bat при помощи кнопки в Qt Quick приложении под windows?

Comment: Делал когда-то прогу для хранения и запуска файлов с использованием Qt Quick: https://github.com/gil9red/ListFiles

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: @gil9red Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, боюсь это автору нужно выкладывать в виде ответа тот код, который ему помог -- там много чего используется, программа сложнее, чем нужно было автору :)

Comment: @gil9red Возможно, получится собрать минимальный необходимый пример? Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, например, [на мой ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/529131/6).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, да думал об этом еще когда писал первый коммент :) выложу позже простенький пример

Answer (score 1):

[Привожу короткий пример](https://github.com/gil9red/QML_run_file).

**main.qml**. Форма: две кнопки, однострочный редактор. Одна кнопка открывает диалог для выбора файла и после выбора записывает путь файла к редактор. Другая по пути в редакторе пытается выполнить запуск файла через объект с++ *Util*.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    width: 300
    height: 300
    visible: true

    RowLayout {
        anchors.leftMargin: 8
        anchors.topMargin: 8
        anchors.rightMargin: 8
        anchors.bottomMargin: 8
        anchors.fill: parent

        TextField {
            id: fileNameTextField
            placeholderText: qsTr("Text Field")
        }

        Button {
            id: openButton
            text: qsTr("...")
            Layout.preferredHeight: 23
            Layout.preferredWidth: 24
            implicitWidth: parent.width

            onClicked: fileDialog.open()

            FileDialog {
                id: fileDialog
                folder: "."
                title: qsTr("Choose a file to open")
                selectMultiple: true
                nameFilters: [ qsTr("All files (*.*)") ]

                onAccepted: {
                    var fileName = fileUrl.toString();

                    // remove prefixed "file:///"
                    fileName = fileName.replace(/^(file:\/{3})/,"");

                    // unescape html codes like '%23' for '#'
                    fileName = decodeURIComponent(fileName);

                    fileNameTextField.text = fileName;
                    console.log(fileName);
                }

                onRejected: fileDialog.close()
            }
        }

        Button {
            id: runButton
            text: qsTr("Run")
            Layout.preferredHeight: 23
            Layout.preferredWidth: 86
            implicitWidth: parent.width

            onClicked: {
                Util.run(fileNameTextField.text);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Util.h/cpp**

```
#ifndef UTIL_H
#define UTIL_H

#include <QObject>

class Util: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

    public slots:
        void run(QString fileName);
};


#endif // UTIL_H
```

//

```
#include "util.h"
#include <QDesktopServices>
#include <QUrl>

void Util::run(QString fileName) {
// Для полного соответствия лучше вызывать из того же каталога, где находится файл.
// Алгоритм на примере python:
//
//    import os
//    old_cwd = os.getcwd()
//    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(file_name))
//    QDesktopServices.openUrl(QUrl.fromLocalFile(file_name))
//    os.chdir(old_cwd)

    QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(fileName));
}
```

**main.cpp**.
**main.qml** находится в файле ресурсов `qrc` под именем `main`.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QDebug>
#include "util.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);   

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QQmlContext* rootContext = engine.rootContext();
    rootContext->setContextProperty("Util", new Util());

    engine.load(QUrl("qrc:/main"));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Файл ресурсов:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file alias="main">main.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```